# Converting data.frame to high-dimensional matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, multidimensional-array, vector

For example, consider the following data

```
> sample.df
  f1 f2   x1   x2   x3
1  2  2 7.28 9.40 5.02
2  1  1 6.30 9.56 3.74
3  2  1 6.88 8.72 3.14
4  1  2 6.68 9.58 3.84
```

I wonder how to write `MAGIC` so that

```
> sample.matrix <- MAGIC(sample.df)
> sample.matrix[1, 1, ]
[1] 6.30 9.56 3.74
> sample.matrix[1, 2, ]
[1] 6.68 9.58 3.84
```

Basically, `sample.matrix[x, y, ]` selects the row in the data frame with `sample.df[sample.df$f1 == x & sample.df$f2 == y, ]`, and then remove the redundant columns indicating the value of `f1` and `f2`. Note that each combination of `(f1, f2)` appears and appears only once in the data frame.

My first thought was `as.matrix` followed by a `dim<-`, but the rows in the data frame are not sorted. Sorting it would take O(n * log(n)), but I just want to create a table, so theoretically the time complexity could be bound by O(n).

It would be better if you could exploit vectorization, if possible.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html pls see 1c and 2a

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea via `matrix`. Note this is not exactly the same as the output you require, but can easily be transformed.

Assuming df is your `sample.df`,

```
m1 <- matrix(do.call(paste, df[with(df, order(f1, f2)),-c(1, 2)]), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
m1[1, 2]
#[1] "6.68 9.58 3.84"
m1[1, 1]
#[1] "6.3 9.56 3.74"
m1[2, 1]
#[1] "6.88 8.72 3.14"
m1[2, 2]
#[1] "7.28 9.4 5.02"
```

You can get them as numeric vectors by splitting, i.e.

```
as.numeric(strsplit(m1[1, 2], ' ')[[1]])
#[1] 6.68 9.58 3.84
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

After re-reading the question again I think we can use `split` without `order`ing to avoid the sorting step. Since `f1` and `f2` are unique for every row, we can do

```
split(sample.df[, -(1:2)], list(sample.df$f1, sample.df$f2))


#$`1.1`
#   x1   x2   x3
#2 6.3 9.56 3.74

#$`2.1`
#    x1   x2   x3
#3 6.88 8.72 3.14

#$`1.2`
#    x1   x2   x3
#4 6.68 9.58 3.84

#$`2.2`
#    x1  x2   x3
#1 7.28 9.4 5.02
```

---

**Original Answer**

I am not exactly clear about the goal but one way is to `order` `sample.df` by `f1`, `f2` and then subset using `Map`

```
new_df <- sample.df[with(sample.df, order(f1, f2)),]

Map(function(x, y) new_df[with(new_df, f1 == x & f2 == y), -(1:2)],
                   new_df$f1, new_df$f2)

#[[1]]
#   x1   x2   x3
#2 6.3 9.56 3.74

#[[2]]
#    x1   x2   x3
#4 6.68 9.58 3.84

#[[3]]
#    x1   x2   x3
#3 6.88 8.72 3.14

#[[4]]
#    x1  x2   x3
#1 7.28 9.4 5.02
```

If the above one is your expected output then every row in `new_df` is the output you want. If you want them as separate list we can also `split` every row

```
split(new_df[, -(1:2)], seq_len(nrow(new_df)))
```

which would give you the same output.

Comment: Can I convert the result of `split` into a vector? `as.numeric` doesn't work. If that's possible, I can use the `dim<-` hack then.

Comment: @nalzok Something like this `split(unlist(sample.df[, -(1:2)], use.names = FALSE), list(sample.df$f1, sample.df$f2), )` ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, but `unlist(split(sample.df[, -(1:2)], list(sample.df$f1, sample.df$f2)), use.names = FALSE)` does the trick!

Comment: ok..I thought you want to maintain the list structure to differentiate between each row. This would return a single vector.

Comment: You are right, and this is what I'm doing now. After `data.vector <- unlist(split(...`, I would do a `dim(data.vector) <- c(2, 2, 3, 4)` to get the list structure back. However, R constructs matrices by column, so I'm still wondering how to do this properly...

Comment: Ah ha, I got it. Just `dim(data.vector) <- c(4, 3, 2, 2)`, and then `data.matrix <- aperm(data.vector, c(3, 4, 1, 2))`.